# call function on browser leave window

Tags: javascript

Hello I want to call API when user close browser so I have use bellow function

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
        var message = 'Sure you want to leave?';
        if (typeof event == 'undefined') {
            event = window.event;
        }
        if (event) {
            event.returnValue = message;
        }
        return message;
    }
```

so this function showing me two buttons "Leave" and "stay"

I want to call API if user click on leave button , but I am not getting any event because it directly close when I click on leave so anyone have any suggestion how can I do this.

Comment: what do you mean by "close API"?

Comment: You can't for security reasons.

Comment: modern browsers kill off http requests when you exit.

Comment: This will never be reliable, because the user can kill the browser by force (eg. by SIGKILL).

Comment: but I need to call api to change value to database when user close browser because I am using this for exam purpose

Comment: I think you should describe why you want to do this. What value do you need to change in database...? There are usually better ways to accomplish similar problems than using javascript "onbeforeunload" event.

Comment: when user has started exam then I am opening that exam in new window with disabling inputs except mouse click , so if during running exam user change tab and start that same exam so I want to show exam already started and if user closing running exam window I want to update value in database that showing user exam is still continue